# Spark sql structured streaming on multiple sources with relatively small amount of data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple sources and each of them receives relatively small amount of data. The schemes of the data received in these sources are the same, so they are used just as a separation of the applications which send the events. The aggregations performed on the data are expensive(at least 200 tasks) which means that I need a lot of processing power. That's ok, but when I have many source with small amount of data it becomes really cost inefficient. So if I run multiple streaming queries against every source this means that I will have ~200*x task where x is the number of the sources. This will be ok as soon as I have a lot of data in every source. My question is if there is a way to combine all the data from the different sources(it's ok also to put all the data in one source) and perform the aggregations on the whole chunk but at the same time not to mix the different applications data. The first thing that came to my mind is to group the data based on the application name, but then I'm extremely limited to the operations I can perform. So is there any way of doing this or I'm trying to achieve something impossible?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you don't need to group by appName  and then aggregate, you just need to aggregate taking into account appName, so you will not be restricted by operations.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I'm not sure what do you mean by "taking into account appName". The problem here is that my data separation is based on app_name. So that the data from one app doesn't mix with the data from another app. And if I have a big amount of data the approach of running aggregations on every stream source will be completely acceptable but when I have several apps with small amount of data it become inefficient and it's not worth it. So how can I need to find a way to combine the data in a way that I still have some sort of data separation using the same amount of processing power.

Comment: I think I got it. So my best idea is to put all the streams in one common Output Sink in kafka and then read it again